# development of an normal GWT Screen with borders

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt2

[image: Develop a screen like this]

i want to develop a **screen as shown in the image** using only GWT , im was using smartGwt and im very much new to gwt can u please tell me how to

> get the border

and the

> dotted lines

? its an urgent requirement

Comment: Can you please Paste your existing code .

Answer (score 0):

You can give GWT's DecoratorPanel panel a try http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDecoratorPanel

You should look through GWT's showcase - http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/

You might most often find the widgets you are looking for with sample code.

You can find GWT sample code here - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsamples

You can extract "samples" the from here - http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/detail?name=gwt-2.5.0.zip